# How to implement paypal without using webview or browser in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment

I am trying to implement paypal in my flutter app without using webview or browser. I have tried "flutter_braintree" and "braintree_payment" packages for flutter. But both of this packages redirect to the web browser. So is there any way to implement paypal in flutter like the native android way. Or can I implement it on native android and build it with flutter? If the answer yes, then how am I gonna achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

The PayPal login should always be a [secure browser view](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/info-security-guidelines/#secure-applications) where you can see the address bar (Chrome Custom Tabs or Safari View Controller). This is by design, since anything else is not secure.

In place of the Braintree SDK there is a new, recently released [Native Checkout SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/) you could have a look at, but I'm not aware of bindings for flutter specifically.